# In Rails, where do I put code responsible for periodically saving data from an external source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

The app I’m developing needs to get some data from a third-party REST API every few minutes and save it to a database.

I’m not sure where this fits in the MVC architecture. My best guess would be to put it in the corresponding models, but seems like I'd be mixing responsibilities.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use [custom rake tasks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) and schedule them using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

There is even a nice [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby), although it is a bit old.

Comment: I'll definitely use that gem, but I'm still not sure where the classes that get the external data and process it go. It's my understanding that the rake tasks will just call them, right? But is there a place for this kind of domain logic besides the models? Thanks a lot!